# What is this black streak and how do i resolve this?

Tags: rendering

A black streak upon rendering in cycles.

Noticed a black streak upon rendering in Cycles. How do I resolve this issue and what caused it?

I am a complete beginner to blender.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I see no black streak...

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/0yTbKqxx/belnder2.png it can be observed in one of the icing drippings. @GordonBrinkmann

Comment: the big "O" shaped black area is a shadow. The small vertical black line is also a shadow - caused by a crease in the topping.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/0yTbKqxx/belnder2.png the black streak can be observed on the icing drip @moonboots

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady oh yeah i was talking about the vertical line which appears like a crack how do avoid that. i tried changing the lightning multiple times.

Comment: If you don't want it to appear like a crack, you should reshape the icing so that there is no more crack/crease. And please, don't repeat the same comment over and over again.

Comment: It looks like an artifact with flipped normals or some dsiturbances in the mesh. Would need the model to say more.
Even a screenshot of the mesh could help.

Comment: A closeup view of the area of interest looks strange.
Recalculate normals didn't help, which would have been my guess.
Maybe the easiest way to go would be to delete a bunch of vertices around that area and rebuild it vertex by vertex.
I.E. connect dots etc.

Comment: Thankyou. ill try it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some weird inner topology there causing the black streak. Select the donut dripping mesh, go to edit mode and choose *Select > Select All by Trait > Interior Faces*. With enabled *X-Ray* mode you should see something like this:

[image]

Hit the `Del` key and select *Faces* to delete all this inner stuff and the black streak should be gone.